# how to stop click counting on multiple buttons at once(with some other Jbutton) in Java

Tags: java, swing

I need a help, I'm looking everywhere but without success,
I'm creating Java gui app, which will have a many of buttons, that buttons will be the some like objects and have a name and price from the SQL, but the quantity will be the number of clicks of buttons,and after calculating the products I need to erase that list, the problem is that everything is working, but when I try to create new list(which is DbutilsTableModel) the  quantity just continue to count from the previous list!
This is the code for erasing button and which predicted to reset all counters to 0(zero):

```
JButton btnBrisiListu = new JButton("Brisi racun listu");  // Button for erasing the list
buttonGroup.add(btnBrisiListu);
btnBrisiListu.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        String naredba1 = " UPDATE ArtikliRacun  SET [Komada]= 0 ";
        String naredba = "SELECT [Naziv],[Komada],[Cena] from ArtikliRacun WHERE Komada > 0"; 


        try {
            Statement stmt = konekcioniObj.createStatement();
            stmt.executeUpdate(naredba1);
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(naredba);  

            table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));

            System.out.println(rs);

        } catch (SQLException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } 

    }
});
```

This is the code for button(some article/product)- the code is the same for all these buttons:

```
JButton button = new JButton("Jelen 0.33");
    buttonGroup.add(button);
    button.setName("Jelen 0.33");       
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        int komada = 0;             
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {


            komada++;

            String naredba1 = " UPDATE ArtikliRacun  SET [Komada]='"+komada+"' WHERE Naziv ='"+button.getName()+"' ";
            String naredba = "SELECT [Naziv],[Komada],[Cena] from ArtikliRacun WHERE Komada > 0"; 

            try {
                Statement stmt = konekcioniObj.createStatement();
                stmt.executeUpdate(naredba1);
                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(naredba);  

                table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));

                System.out.println(rs);

            } catch (SQLException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } 

            String naredba3 = "SELECT cast(SUM (Ukupno) as varchar(255)) as total from ArtikliRacun";
                try {
                    Statement pst = konekcioniObj.createStatement();
                ResultSet   res = pst.executeQuery(naredba3);
                 if(res.next()){
                     String sum = res.getString("total");
                     textField.setText(sum);
                     System.out.println(sum);
                 }
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


        }

    });
```

Comment: Post the DbUtils methods you're using

Comment: I'm imported rs2xml.jar library, and set the table with just this line of code:  table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));

Comment: `komada` is an instance field of the anonymous `ActionListener` associated with one of the `JButton`s.  This will make it impossible for your to reset.  Instead, `komada` needs to be defined within a context which would allow both button's `ActionListener`s to reference, this way, when you reset the list, you could simply set `komada` to `0`.  Another choice might be to figure out if it's possible to perform an increment directly within the SQL statement

Comment: Something like `UPDATE ArtikliRacun  SET [Komada]=[Komada] + 1 WHERE Naziv ='"+button.getName()+"'`. Now, having said that, it's also time to start learning about [Using Prepared Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

Comment: Thank you MadProgrammer, this way with sql statement is working!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like

UPDATE ArtikliRacun SET [Komada]=[Komada] + 1 WHERE Naziv ='"+button.getName()+"'

This is working!!!!
Thank you  @MadProgrammer